# Javascript: Hex to String without converting to ascii, int or xyz

Tags: javascript, decode, node-red, payload, lorawan

I have a byte array.

`sensor_id = [bytes[36],bytes[35],bytes[34],bytes[33]]`

It holds the following hexadecimal values:

`0x69, 0x72, 0x33, 0x88`

I need to merge `69 72 33 88` into a string value without conversion => "69723388".

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the hexadecimal values to string by using `toString(16)`. For more read the [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

```js
const arr = [0x69, 0x72, 0x33, 0x88];
const base16string = arr.map(item => item.toString(16));

console.log(base16string);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I think this is what i've been looking for.

Comment: Glad to know that.